# Using splash with themes ovewrite all window backgrounds

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-theme

I am using

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- draw performance -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@color/background</item>
  </style>

<style name="Splash">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

in my activity:

```
<activity
      android:name=".logged.MainDrawerActivity"
      android:theme="@style/Splash"/>
```

and then

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Base); // To remove splash style
```

That works, the splash `Drawable` appears and go out after the `Activity` is loaded, but now all the `Fragment`s inside that `Activity` have `android:windowBackground` with `splash` and not `@color/background` why?

Comment: Have you tried calling `setTheme` before `super.onCreate()`?

Comment: You need to override the Theme in the onCreateView of your fragment I guess.